# Не могу понять в чем ошибка PHP/Call to undefined function

Tags: php

```
class Main{

    private $connect;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect = Connect::toConnect();
        readAndWriteRegions($this->connect);

    }

    function readAndWriteRegions($connect)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM region';
        foreach ($connect->query($sql) as $row) {
            print $row['name'] . "\t";
            print $row['color'] . "\t";
            print $row['calories'] . "\n";
        }
    }
}

$main = new Main();
```

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не видит метод `readAndWriteRegions`?

Я знакомлюсь с ООП в PHP, имею некий опыт в C#, у меня еще один вопрос, будет ли работать если я сделаю статический класс, в нем буду хранить константы/публичные переменные, которые буду заполнять из БД все один раз за сессию. Например, мне надо вытягивать из БД регионы и города, я хотел сделать массив объектов регионы, которые в свою очередь имеют массивы объектов городов.

Эти данные мне нужно использовать во многих местах сайта и что бы каждый раз не дергать БД я подумал что лучше считать один раз и обращаться к статическому классу к массивам этих объектов. Правильный ли это будет подход?

Еще я заметил что поля класса можно инициализировать в основном только в конструкторе класса, но не будет же ни 1 экземпляра в этом статическом классе или все равно будет работать или в php нету понятия статического класса?

Comment: А `$this->` кто за вас будет писать? И ещё, правила хорошего тона советуют явно прописывать модификаторы доступа к методам класса

Comment: Доступ к **любым** нестатическим членам класса только через this `this>readAndWriteRegions(...)`

Comment: Зачем в `readAndWriteRegions`  вы передаёте аргумент? Он же у вас как атрибут класса есть. И к нему доступ есть из любого метода класса (не статического)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `$this`

`$this->readAndWriteRegions($this->connect);`